# How to open a tab/pane in the same directory in Windows Terminal with Fish shell

Tags: fish, windows-terminal

Microsoft has a guide how to do that for other shells such as bash and zsh but not for fish shell.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/tutorials/new-tab-same-directory

Answer (score 1):

open your fish config file located at ~/.config/fish/config.fish and add to it the following function:

```
function storePathForWindowsTerminal --on-variable PWD
    if test -n "$WT_SESSION"
      printf "\e]9;9;%s\e\\" (wslpath -w "$PWD")
    end
end
```

**Explanation:**

This function is a hook that is called whenever current path is changed.
It will confirm current session is opened by Windows Terminal (By verifying environment variable $WT_SESSION exists), and will send Operating System Command (OSC 9;9;), with the Windows equivalent path (wslpath -w) of current path.
This sequence will let Windows Terminal know that the path was changed and when a new tab / pane will be created, Windows Terminal will use the changed path as current directory.